# “Your security settings have blocked a local application from running” Java 8

Tags: java, security, permission-denied

I am trying to run a small applet in my Chrome window, but am getting the error message.

I do see all the replies telling me to change my security to medium, but that option does not exist in version 8. So far several hours of googling and asking help from classmates has brought no progress.

Can anyone suggest something please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Medium** was removed in Java 8u20:

> Medium (removed from Java 8 Update 20 and later versions)
>   Only unsigned applications that request all permissions are blocked. All other applications are allowed to run with security prompts. Selecting the Medium security level is not recommended and will make your computer more vulnerable should you run a malicious application.

Keep in mind, this only applies to *unsigned* applets that request *all* permissions.

**What to do**

To run these applets, you now must add the site to the exception list under the Security tab when you access your Java settings from the Control Panel.

If the applet is not on a website, you must use the [applet viewer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/appletviewer.html), which allows you to run applets outside of a browser

Comment: I don't have any site that I am running it from yet, this is coming straight off my hard drive. I tried adding the file:///[location] etc but I still get a blocked message.

Comment: If at all possible stop using applets.

Comment: @MeBigFatGuy You should post that comment under his question

Comment: Sorry for the delay Vince, been away from the computer for a while. I already have been using the appletviewer, running it through NetBeans. I guess I will just have to find some place online I can use to test out browser function. Thank you for your help though!  @MeBigFatGuy - this is for a beginners course I just started.

Comment: @VinceEmigh - apparently I do not have enough reputation yet to up vote you. I did mark it as answered though!

Comment: @DanielJamieson No problem. And for the record, the reason you must use the appletviewer is because applets are meant to be ran in a browser, not on your desktop directly. If not in a browser, there's no reason to use an applet. After the security update, you cannot run an applet normally; it must be ran using the appletviewer or within a browser. Applets come with security risks; I highly suggest looking into [this](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_applet#Security)